# Split time intervals on the hour

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data set:

```
  tbldataid          TS                     EndTS
> HX32.3401 10/2/2017 11:49:34 PM   10/3/2017 12:01:57 AM
> HX32.3403 10/3/2017 12:02:48 AM   10/3/2017 12:08:34 AM
> HX32.3425 10/3/2017 2:50:57 AM    10/3/2017 2:50:58 AM
> HX32.3428 10/3/2017 4:06:15 AM    10/3/2017 6:09:19 AM
```

I would like to to essentially 'split' these intervals on the hour, such as:

```
tbldataid               TS                EndTS
HX32.3401   10/2/2017 11:49:34 PM   10/2/2017 11:59:99 PM
HX32.3401   10/2/2017 12:00:00 PM   10/3/2017 12:01:57 AM
HX32.3403   10/3/2017 12:02:48 AM   10/3/2017 12:08:34 AM
HX32.3425   10/3/2017 2:50:57 AM    10/3/2017 2:50:58 AM
HX32.3428   10/3/2017 4:06:15 AM    10/3/2017 4:59:99 AM
HX32.3428   10/3/2017 5:00:00 AM    10/3/2017 5:59:99 AM
HX32.3428   10/3/2017 6:00:00 AM    10/3/2017 6:09:19 AM
```

Here is my code so far (credit for the idea goes to @Dumitrescu Bogdan, [Split call data to 15 minute intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416913/split-call-data-to-15-minute-intervals)):

```
SELECT [tbldataid],[TS],
   IIF([EndTS]<=dateadd("n",60*((datediff("n",0,[TS]/60))+.99),0), 
        [EndTS], 
        dateadd("n", 60*(datediff("n",0,[TS]/60)+.99),0)) 
        as [End] 
FROM tbldata


UNION ALL 

SELECT t2.[tbldataid], t2.[TS],
   IIF(t1.[EndTS]<=dateadd("n",60*((datediff("n",0, t2.[EndTS])/60)+1),0), 
         t1.[EndTS], 
         dateadd("n",60*((datediff("n",0,t2.[EndTS])/60)+1),0)) 
         as [End] 
FROM 
   tbldata t1 
   LEFT JOIN tbldata t2
   ON t1.[tbldataid]=t2.[tbldataid]
Where t2.[EndTS]<IIF(t1.[EndTS]<=dateadd("n",60*((datediff("n",0,t2.[EndTS])/60)+1),0),
                                   t1.[EndTS],
                                   dateadd("n",60*((datediff("n",0,t2.[EndTS])/60)+1),0));
```

The second half (after 'union all') doesn't produce any result, the first half produces the following:

```
tbldataid             TS                     End
HX32.3401   10/2/2017 11:49:34 PM   10/2/2017 11:59:00 PM
HX32.3403   10/3/2017 12:02:48 AM   10/3/2017 12:08:34 AM
HX32.3425   10/3/2017 2:50:57 AM    10/3/2017 2:50:58 AM
HX32.3428   10/3/2017 4:06:15 AM    10/3/2017 4:59:00 AM
```

Thanks, I'm a beginner. I understand the first part; admittedly I don't understand the second half

I'm open to other solutions.

I'm using MS-Access 2010

Comment: The other question shows tags for SQL-Server, no mention of Access. It is also a very different SQL statement. Access SQL cannot do 'looping' to create records. Use VBA procedure that writes records to another table.

Comment: @June7 I tried to modify the code for Access SQL and got the first half working.  'Looping' was probably the wrong word.  That whole statement was convoluted and unnecessary so I removed it from my question.

Comment: Semantics. Doesn't matter what you call it, AFIAK, Access SQL can't do what you want it to.

Comment: @June7: Never say never ...

Comment: Also see this: [How to create a time series in Access and can use it in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835890/how-to-create-a-time-series-in-access-and-can-use-it-in-a-query/28836840#28836840)

Comment: Nice to learn something new. I knew about Cartesian, just didn't recognize its application here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a *Cartesian* query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tblData.tblDataId, 
    IIf([TimeStart] > DateAdd("h",[Factor],CDate(Fix([Timestart]*24)/24)),
        [TimeStart],
        DateAdd("h",[Factor],CDate(Fix([Timestart]*24)/24))) AS TSStart, 
    IIf([TimeEnd] < DateAdd("s",3599,DateAdd("h",[Factor],CDate(Fix([Timestart]*24)/24))),
        [TimeEnd],
        DateAdd("s",3599,DateAdd("h",[Factor],CDate(Fix([Timestart]*24)/24)))) AS TSEnd
FROM 
    qdxFactor, 
    tblData
WHERE
    qdxFactor.Factor Between 0 And DateDiff("h",[TimeStart],[TimeEnd]);
```

using this other saved Cartesian query (*qdxFactor*):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca;
```

Result:

```
tblDataId   TSStart             TSEnd
    3401    2017-10-02 23:49:34 2017-10-02 23:59:59
    3401    2017-10-03 00:00:00 2017-10-03 00:01:57
    3403    2017-10-03 00:02:48 2017-10-03 00:08:34
    3425    2017-10-03 02:50:57 2017-10-03 02:50:58
    3428    2017-10-03 04:06:15 2017-10-03 04:59:59
    3428    2017-10-03 05:00:00 2017-10-03 05:59:59
    3428    2017-10-03 06:00:00 2017-10-03 06:09:19
```

Second example with:

```
tblDataId   TimeStart           TimeEnd
    3430    2017-10-07 02:08:24 2017-10-07 14:09:30
```

Result:

```
tblDataId   TSStart             TSEnd
    3430    2017-10-07 02:08:24 2017-10-07 02:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 03:00:00 2017-10-07 03:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 04:00:00 2017-10-07 04:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 05:00:00 2017-10-07 05:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 06:00:00 2017-10-07 06:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 07:00:00 2017-10-07 07:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 08:00:00 2017-10-07 08:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 09:00:00 2017-10-07 09:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 10:00:00 2017-10-07 10:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 11:00:00 2017-10-07 11:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 12:00:00 2017-10-07 12:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 13:00:00 2017-10-07 13:59:59
    3430    2017-10-07 14:00:00 2017-10-07 14:09:30
```

Comment: I wonder how well that Cartesian will perform on a very large dataset. I have never seen any system tables used like this. This is very new to me.

Comment: @Gustav thank you, I'm going to study up on Cartesian :)  Good performance so far, 3 sec on a 4000 record table

Comment: @June7 and Jordan: Cartesian is just a fine label for _multiplying_ - combining two tables with, say, 3 and 4 records returns 12 records. Output can be limited by adding a Where clause as done above. By nature, you have to be careful applying the method on large tables.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you.  I did want to bring up one thing, when the the start and end differs in meridiem, and diff is >12 hrs, such as `10/7/2017 2:08:24 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM` I get the following result:

Comment: `10/7/2017 2:08:24 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 3:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 4:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 5:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 6:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 7:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 8:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 9:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM,
10/7/2017 10:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 10:59:59 AM,
10/7/2017 11:00:00 AM 10/7/2017 11:59:59 AM,
10/7/2017 12:00:00 PM 10/7/2017 12:59:59 PM,
10/7/2017 1:00:00 PM 10/7/2017 1:59:59 PM,
10/7/2017 2:00:00 PM 10/7/2017 2:09:30 PM`

Comment: No. The result is appended in my original answer. Perhaps your table fields are not of data type _Date_ but _Text_. Never ever (as in _never_) store date/time as text.

Comment: @Gustav  Once again you are correct.  TSEnd was stored as _Text_