# Group By Time Interval In Access Select Query From Form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database containing data from loggers that run 24/7. I am trying to design a front end that allows users to choose a date range, then export the data to excel and graph it. I have that bit working but the limit for exporting is 65,000 records so I need to implement a form of aggregation. To do this, I am trying to have a list box on the main form that contains intervals "15 minutes", "30 Minutes", "1 Hour", etc. I'm then trying to use those values as criteria to filter the select query that is used for the graphing but I can't get it to work. The query is:

```
SELECT Data.Location, Data.Date_Time, Data.LEVEL, Data.Time
FROM Data
WHERE (((Data.Time)=IIf([Forms]![Export].[List13]="1 Hour",([Data].[Time]) 
      Like "*00:00*",[Data].[Time])) 
AND 
      ((Data.Date) Between [Forms]![Export].[txtstartdate] And [Forms]!
      [Export].[txtenddate]));
```

I only have one criteria here in the query but ideally I would like to have many using compounding iif statements. I want the query to see "1 Hour" and only select times with 0 minutes and 0 seconds but it currently is returning no results. I am also open to doing this differently if this is not the best way to go about things.

Comment: You may get some inspiration from [Split time intervals on the hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568984/split-time-intervals-on-the-hour/46573967#46573967)

Comment: 1) Please clarify what you mean by "form of aggregation".  In the paragraph after the code it sounds like you want to filter based on exact time values. That is not aggregation.  2) Is Data.Time column of DateTime data type? 3) Show a _limited_ set of source values plus what output you want/expect.  (Note: Edit the question to improve it and add useful details.  Don't just submit this info in the comments, especially sample data.)